# Web app targeting iOS, Android and WP7?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, windows-phone-7

I'm about to start on a new web application project where I need to support iOS, Android and Windows mobile 7. Is there a framework that will support all three?
In the past I've used Sencha Touch for iOS and Android, but it would be nice if there was a framework for all three systems.
I would like it to be as native looking as possible since this is a demand from the client.

Answer (score 3):

I will use [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) for this. You can refer official PhoneGap site at http://www.phonegap.com/

It supports six platforms which includes ios, android, blackberry, windows, symbian, palm os..

You can refer complete chart here  for different features in different mobile os http://www.phonegap.com/features

You can see for Windows its still coming soon.
https://build.phonegap.com/

However they are updating with Bada & MeeGo..

Comment: Thanks. I looked at Phonegaps website, but they don't have support for WP 7 yet.

Comment: PhoneGap support for WP7 is waiting on IE9 mobile/ the Mango update.

Answer (score 0):

W3C has a list of mobile web app best practices. Please check this link

http://www.w3.org/TR/mwabp/

I hope this will help you in designing a mobile web applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Although still in alpha you may want to consider using jQuery Mobile http://jquerymobile.com/ for the UI. It does have some WP7 support, but expect this to get a lot better after the IE9 mobile/Mango update.